# Detecting when user touches a link

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to detect when the user has touched a link within a web page versus when they have touched any other part of the page, but its not working - what happens is in the following code the alert "touched a non link" pops up wherever I touch, regardless of if its a link.

What is there a problem with this code?

```
function addListeners()
{  
    alert('adding listeners');

    // Attach the listener for touches on non-links to the document node
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchesOnNonLinksListerner, false);

    // Attach the listener for touches on links to the anchor nodes
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var index = 0; index < links.length; ++index)
    {
        links[index].addEventListener("touchstart", touchesOnNonLinksListerner, false);
    }
}; 

function touchesOnNonLinksListerner(event)
// Catches touches anywhere in the document
{
    alert("touched  a non link");
}

function touchesOnLinksListener(event)
// Listens for touches which occur on links, then prevents those touch events from bubbling up to trigger the touchesOnNonLinksListerner
{
    alert("touched a link");
    if (typeof event == "undefined")
    {
        event = window.event;
    }

    event.stopPropegation();
}
```

Comment: You misspelled `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: If it's not a typo in your post here, that should be event.stopPropagation() - ..pa.. not ..pe..

Comment: Also misspelled `Listener` in several places.

Comment: This is my first attempt at Javascript. I ran this through jslint first and it was ok. How can I tell if I have mistyped anything?

Comment: You can use the error console in your browser. For example, in Firefox 10 it's opened with Tools->Web Developer->Error Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have attached touchesOnNonLinksListerner to your links as well. Attach touchesOnLinksListener instead!